# Compare and highlight

Tags: excel, compare, highlight

I compare 2 tables with numbers and need to highlight number red in TABLE A if it's less than number on TABLE B.
Could you please help with this?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear formatting from and select ColumnsA:C then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1<E1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the conditional formatting function build in within Excel, and than use the condition that the values of table A are colored when they are lower than the values in table B.

[image]

[Link for more information](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)